# Proper mapping in Shading view

Tags: node-editor, vector-mapping

I have obtained some very nice 3D models complete with textures. I have been trying to replicate the exact colours and contours of the model as posted by the artist but am having problems connecting the textures with the appropriate nodes. I have the following textures:
1. AlbedoAO - Connected to the base color of the principaled BSDF
2. Normal - Connected to the normal of the principaled through the normal map node
3. Gloss - Emission??
4. Illumination - Emission??
5. Metalness - Connected to the metallic of the principaled although I don't see a difference.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Am I correct in my mapping? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you are correct in your mapping.  if the emission texture is black and white, its a map to tell the shader where the object should emit light, (it would be used as a factor between the principled node and an emission node.)  If it has color, it's a color map for your emission.
I hope this is helpful.

Comment: OK cool thanks mate. Cheers!

Comment: glad I could help.